# What is Atmel's 2x5 ICSP connector called?

Tags: cables, terminology, icsp

I'm looking for a male connector that fits in the left female connector shown in the image. My goal is to break each lead out to holes on a breadboard. What is that kind of 2x5 connector called?

[image]

Searching for ICSP connectors doesn't help me.

Comment: By the way, I suppose this, wires, a USB male-male cable and a laptop is all I'd need to program an AVR (specifically atmega128)?

Comment: It's just a 2x5 0.1" header. Buy a longer one and break off what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are 0.100", or [2.54mm pitch headers](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Headers-Wire-Housings/_/N-ay0lo?P=1z0wxp6Z1z0wxg6&FS=True). They are sold in long strips of single or double rows and you can break off however many pins you need. There are also versions with shrouds and various keying mechanisms to prevent backwards connection.

Here's the basic type:

[image: male header]

Shrouded types (like starblue mentions in comment) look like this:

[image: shrouded male header]

Comment: You can also get them shrouded, so you can only plug in the connector in the correct orientation: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/shrouded-box-head-2x5